Why does text displayed with system("type example.txt") appear different than using type example.txt in the terminal?
I have written a string to a .txt file, and am trying to output it to the terminal, but something is going wrong during this and I'm getting a bunch of �'s.
The code in question:
std::locale::global(std::locale("")); //sets locale to allow unicode full blocks
initializeArray(); //initializes all pixels to be 2 full blocks
std::wstring currentFrame = renderFrame(); //sets a wstring to the formatted and finalized frame
writeFrame(currentFrame); //writes a frame to a .txt file
system("cls"); //clears terminal screen
system("type frameBuffer1.txt"); //is supposed to output the txt file correctly

Evidence of the crime:

I have tried every terminal I have installed. I have checked that the .txt file contains the correct information. I have tried many locale settings.
I expected the two outputs to be the same.

Please add code to your question as text, not images.

You are using two different type commands, one is an alias to PowerShell Get-Content command and the other is a built-in command of cmd.

@n. m. could be an AI Thank you, changing it to system("powershell.exe Get-Content frameBuffer1.txt"); fixed it.

Every call to system() runs a new instance of cmd.exe. Any locales you set in your code have no effect on system().

The behaviour of system() is implementation defined, so observable behavior of your code can (and will!) vary between platforms, compiler/library, and user configuration (e.g.  choice of command interpreters) i.e. beyond control of your program.  cmd and powershell are windows specific.   To allow your program more control of its visible behaviour, you wish to use Windows Console functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions ).  There are comparable libraries/capabilities on other platforms (e.g. ncurses).
